# Customise JScrollBar arrow

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I would like to create JScrollBar with increase and decrease buttons at the bottom in case of vertical scrollbar as shown in the image attached. (Mac OS Style)

I need something like

------------O-----------<>

instead of

<----------O-------------->

Could you please help me with this?

[image: ScrollBar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for the ScrollBarUI or one of the L&F implementations, to see how the individual Look And Feel classes achieve what they achieve. You will then need to re-write the paint method to draw your version.

[here is the source code for the BasicL&F](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicScrollBarUI-source.html).

However, I would also suggest searching for a L&F that already does this, as I am sure someone has already done this in one of the L&F platforms.